# Selenium not able to access website hosted in another Docker container

Tags: docker, selenium, docker-compose

Any docker, Selenium expert, I would appreciate your help!

I have a web application(LNMP), and I use docker at my local as dev environment.

Now, I am trying to add an additional Selenium container so I can use it for automated testing (https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome-debug).

I couldn't figure out how to set up the connection from Selenium container to my application container(Nginx), because the website is not published.

When I develop at my local, I use a test domain, and I connect to the website by editing the host file at my local.

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 website.test
```

I have tried adding the Selenium container in the yaml file, looks like it was successful, and I am able to use a VNC client from the host to connect to the container.

But I always got Connection Refused when I try to access the website from the Selenium browser. Looks like the DNS works otherwise Chrome would give me a DNS error rather than connection refuse.

My yaml file looks like, as you can see, I added a Selenium container(browser_chrome) and a network(testing). app is the original Nginx container.

```
networks:
  testing:

  
version: "3"
services:
  browser_chrome:
      image: selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.8.1
      ports:
        - "5900:5900"
      networks:
        - testing
  app:
      networks:
        testing:
          aliases:
            - "website.test"
```

This is the original docker file without the Selenium setup, https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento/blob/master/compose/docker-compose.yml, basically, I added the Selenium container(browser_chrome) and the network(testing) to connect them.

I only know the basic stuff of docker, so any help would be appreciated!

:)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to create static network to work with this and leave docker to fit it itself = less problems in future (at least that's my opinion). By not specifying docker network in compose file you leave docker to create network called `default` (container point of view), from host point of view called `<stack-name>_default`

Second thing you have to understand is how networking and connection between two containers in stack works -> Here for connection between containers you have to use service names (in your case `app`) as docker automatically creates DNS records for it

Here is simple compose file to test validity of above:

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: containous/whoami
  client:
    image: appropriate/curl
    command: "curl -vvv http://server"
```

And output from console and service logs

```
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test
Creating network test_default
Creating service test_server
Creating service test_client

$ docker service logs -f test_client
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | * Rebuilt URL to: http://server/
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 10.0.5.2...
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | * TCP_NODELAY set
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | * Connected to server (10.0.5.2) port 80 (#0)
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | > GET / HTTP/1.1
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | > Host: server
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | > User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | > Accept: */*
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | > 
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | < Date: Tue, 01 Jun 2021 09:54:21 GMT
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | < Content-Length: 162
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | < 
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | { [162 bytes data]
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | Hostname: 7d91b392ac0a
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | IP: 127.0.0.1
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | IP: 10.0.5.3
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | IP: 172.18.0.4
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | RemoteAddr: 10.0.5.4:45600
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | GET / HTTP/1.1
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | Host: server
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | Accept: */*
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | 
100   162  100   162    0     0  23142      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 27000
test_client.1.fv8dq5b80dkk@...    | * Connection #0 to host server left intact
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was able to use https://app:8443 to connect to the app Nginx, but I was redirected to https://website.test in the browser and got a DNS error saying the domain couldn't be resolved. if I have to use the domain to test, how I can set up the DNS?

Comment: cmon mate ... setting up nginx is out of scope your question. More over setting up DNS server is even farther. First of all you have to grip basic functionality of networking and docker. Do not start at the end. For now use IP:PORT for checking functionality

Comment: My question is if I have to use domain to access the website, how I can setup the DNS between the Selenium and Nginx container. I have tried using the container name, based on your comment, it allowed me to connect to the Nginx container.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your docker compose file, browser section:

```
    extra_hosts:
      - "website.test:host-gateway"
```

This will make an entry in your browser container's /etc/hosts file that will correctly resolve `website.test` to a correct IP address.